# Наполягати і настоювати - синоніми?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

У мовленні та на письмі вживаю лише слово наполягати, але нещодавно у Є.Д.Чак прочитала, що настоювати теж відповідає літературній нормі і може використовуватися у значенні слова наполягати. Чи це справді так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 5, 1974. — Стор. 203](http://sum.in.ua/s/nastojuvaty):

> **НАСТОЮВАТИ** 1, юю, юєш, *недок[онане]*, **НАСТОЯТИ**, ою, оїш, *док[онаний вид]*, на чому, *з інфін[ітивом]*, *[і]з спол[учником]* щоб. Посилено добиватися, вимагати виконання чого-небудь; наполягати.
>
> > *Боюсь я того оглядання, бо як залізе він з дзеркалом в горло, то коли б ще.. не трапилася [кровотеча]; але Сергій Костянтинович сам настоює на тому огляданні* (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 322);
> >
> > *Він чув у телефонну трубку, що дочка.. говорила з ним уже плачучи. Вона настоювала кілька разів повторити слова Захара, які стосувалися її* (Іван Ле, Право.., 1957, 263);
> >
> > *— Оддав [парафію]. Громада настояла на своєму* (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 69);
> >
> > *— Я настояла, щоб Василь Іванович знову ліг* (Олекса Гуреїв, Осок, друзі, 1946, 54);
> >
> > *Він умів, коли вимагали обставини, настояти на своєму, сказати тверде і владне слово* (Гордій Коцюба, Нові береги, 1959, 347).

Причому варто дивитися навіть не на сам словник (звісно, жоден словник не буває бездоганним, трапляються помилки і перекручування), а на приклади вжитку в літературі. Леся Українка і Іван Нечуй-Левицький достатньо авторитетні письменники. А якщо пошукати в «Google Книгах», то можна знайти й інші цікаві імена: Іван Франко, Михайло Коцюбинський.

Висновок: **так, звісно, теж відповідає літературній нормі**.

<sub>Post Scriptum: Хоча є й інші погляди, наприклад, [тут](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/) і [тут](//movnyk.com.ua/question/surzik-nastoyuvati-na/) — але оскільки вони свої погляди жодним чином не аргументують, то я вважаю за краще довіряти Лесі Українці, Нечуй-Левицькому, Франку і Коцюбинському.</sub>

Comment: Гм, дивно. Моʼ, в мене якийсь інший Інтернет, але ґуґління по фразі *"але Сергій Костянтинович сам настоює"* [дає 6 результатів](https://www.google.com/search?q="але+Сергій+Костянтинович+сам+настоює"), включно з СУМнозвісним СУМом. Я *наполягаю*, що *«настоюють»* на апельсинових скоринках. А на думці *наполягають*. Чи може таке бути, щоб СУМ посилався на твір Л.У., якого не існує? І взагалі, вважаю, що нам як спільноті варто переглянути наше ставлення до СУМу. Авжеж, добре мати під рукою словник з пошуком, але щось тут не те. :-(

Comment: UPD. Перепрошую, запитання знято (слава Bing). Наґуґлилося [тут](https://issuu.com/72522/docs/lesya_ukrajinka.t.11), стор. 204-205. У тому ж листі Леся Українка: (1) звертається до батьків *«Любі моі мама і папа»*, загубивши кличний відмінок; (2) *«мені часом аж досадно»* (а не «прикро»); (3) *«настільки поправитись, щоб їхати»* (а не «одужати»); (4) *«він завжди просить **іменно** мене»* (це взагалі мене вбило наповал — це ж не лист Вєрки Сердючки, врешті-решт) і ще з десяток менш значних… ем… неоднозначних конструкцій. Тепер маю питання до Лесі Українки, але не до вашої відповіді. :-)

Comment: «Чи може таке бути, щоб СУМ посилався на твір <…>, якого не існує?» — теоретично так, але практично ймовірніше, що просто якийсь твір не викладено в інтернет. [Досадно](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24263&page=815), [поправлятися](http://sum.in.ua/s/popravljatysja) — не намагайтесь позбавити українську мову її лексичного багатства. Так, Леся Українка може помилятися (щоденники вона, здається, писала німецькою (чи то Марко Вовчок?) — і десь жалілася, якщо я не сплутав, що майже почала забувати мову (чи то Шевченко?)) — але ж вона не єдина.

Comment: Не єдина. Але тут одне з двох: або ми вважаємо письменницю взірцем і тримаємо високу планку вимог до неї, або декляруємо, що кожен має право писати äк öму зручно, але тоді це не взірець. :-) І — так, щоразу переконуюся стосовно того, що джерела треба перевіряти, навіть Лесю Українку.

Comment: Про що _ӓ_ і кажу. Дивувавсӓ, коли деӓкі особи брали за основу _поетичні твори_ і вказували, що са́ме так треʼ писати (наьголовніша проблема післӓ цӧго: вжив _[в·у](https://zbruc.eu/node/41931)_). Моӓ основа: коли ё лӧґіка подібного використов_ува_ннӓ (ось чому ӓ незадоволениь до _безлоґічного_ ставлненнӓ до наростка _‑ува‑_ і так далі).

Answer (score 2):

Більшість словників стверджують, що *настоювати* і *наполягати* синоніми в значенні добиватись свого. Також обидва слова присутні в цьому значенні в літературній мові. Все ж, на мою думку, наявність омонімів як і повних синонімів ускладнює використання мови, тому я раджу використовувати *настоювати* коли йдеться про приготування настоянок, а *наполягати* коли йдеться про намагання досягти свого.

Цікаво, що пані Євгенія Чак у своїй праці 1969 каже:

> Проте з погляду сучасної норми певна перевага відчувається у слова *наполягати*. Можливо, це пояснюється тим, що в слова *настоювати* є омонім (порівн. *настоювати* в значенні «приготувати настій чогось на чомусь»).

А ось як на ці два слова реагує [Online Corrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/):

[image]